# WPF C# implementing a resize grip

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, .net-4.0

i want to implement a resize grip to my tool. I know that i can activate a grip by setting `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"` but i want to grip to be in an Grid, which is only visible on Hovering. 
I made a Grid with an Image

```
<Grid x:Name="gridResize" Background="Transparent" >
    <Image x:Name="resizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Height="30" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="27"  
           Source="UserControls/Images/sizegrip.png"/>
</Grid>
```

And i have to handle these Events in Code:

```
private void ResizeGrip_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private void GridResize_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    gridResize.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}

private void GridResize_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    gridResize.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Does anyone knows how to implement the Mouse Down Method?

Comment: Are you sure you are not just looking for this  : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/gridsplitter/ ?

Comment: Few advises: use `Thumb` for resize or/and drag something. It provides easy to use event [Thumb.DragDelta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb.dragdelta(v=vs.110).aspx) which will provide you mouse movement deltas for X and Y. If you want to resize a grid or any other UI element, better use grid with 3x3 rowsXcolumns and put 8 thumbs at side rows\columns so you will easy implement resize for each direction.

Comment: Random thought: If the Visibility is set to Hidden, does it even get mouse events?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer No, it wont :D i have to hide the Image :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example (Note I used a Border instead of the image, but changing it is straight forward)

**Xaml**

```
 <Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test" 
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    PreviewMouseMove="window_PreviewMouseMove">

<Grid>
    <Grid Background="Red" x:Name="gridResize"  Margin="236,235,0,0" >
        <Border Focusable="True" Background="Black" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.2" x:Name="resizeGrip" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="27" 
                PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="resizeGrip_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="resizeGrip_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"  >
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter  Property="Opacity" Value="1.0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeNWSE"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

**Code**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    Point _startPosition;
    bool _isResizing = false;
    private void resizeGrip_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Mouse.Capture(resizeGrip))
        {
            _isResizing = true;
            _startPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        }
    }

    private void window_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isResizing)
        {
            Point currentPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
            double diffX = currentPosition.X - _startPosition.X;
            double diffY = currentPosition.Y - _startPosition.Y;
            double currentLeft = gridResize.Margin.Left;
            double currentTop = gridResize.Margin.Top;
            gridResize.Margin = new Thickness(currentLeft + diffX, currentTop + diffY, 0, 0);
            _startPosition = currentPosition;
        }
    }

    private void resizeGrip_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isResizing == true)
        {
            _isResizing = false;
            Mouse.Capture(null);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: In case i use the event SizeChanged to make sure the window will keep its Proportions,   if (diffX < diffY) this.Height = ActualHeight + diffY;
                else this.Height = ActualHeight + diffX; will make it. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The code in the accepted answer does not work (see [wpf: capturing mouse does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001016/wpf-capturing-mouse-does-not-work)). Use thumb instead:

```
<Thumb Name="ResizeGripper" DragDelta="ResizeGripper_DragDelta" />

private void ResizeGripper_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    Width -= e.HorizontalChange;
}
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-resize-a-canvas-by-using-a-thumb